# Make an order between two processes childs P1 and P2

Tags: c, fork, semaphore

I try to solve a little order problem between two childs processes P1 and P2. I want to have this order : P1 active then P2 active then P1 active then P2 active then etc. I think you understand the idea and when one process becomes active then he just make active the other one process. So I want the both process active one after the other one.

I create my process with this way :

```
int process_order(int n) {
  pid_t pid1, pid2;
  pid1 = fork();
  if(pid1 == -1) {
    perror("Error forking process : ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } else if(pid1 == 0) { /* Child 1 */
    /* Make active P2 */
  } else {
    pid2 = fork();
    if(pid2 == -1) {
      perror("Error forking process : ");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if(pid2 == 0) { /* Child 2 */
      /* Make active P1 */
    } else {
      wait(NULL);
      wait(NULL);
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

I'm searching a very simple way to have this order. Maybe with semaphore, pipe or signal no ?

Comment: The operating system, not you, schedules processes, but yes, any of the three things you mention can be used to synchronize the things that those processes do.

Comment: A process is an independent entity that gets scheduled by the OS, that's the point of creating one. Why would you want them to alternate? If it is to do double-buffering then use semaphores.

Comment: It's for a switch context and the first thing I want to do it's to set this order but I meet some problems to implement that. The main problem is how I can comminucate between two process to say to be active for one and suspend for the other one.